# Unable to deploy flask app to heroku: ImportError: No module named xyz

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, flask

It seems like this question has been ask multiple times around SO already but none of the solutions given so far has been what I need.

I have a flask app. tree shown as below

[image]

After pushing to heroku master, trying to access the page will give me the following error (shorter version)
    2016-07-13T05:48:07.793783+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app.Views import home

```
2016-07-13T05:48:07.793783+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/Views/home.py", line 3, in <module>
2016-07-13T05:48:07.793785+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/Helpers/APIHelper.py", line 1, in <module>
2016-07-13T05:48:07.793784+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app.Helpers.APIHelper import *
2016-07-13T05:48:07.793785+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app.Models.flight import *
2016-07-13T05:48:07.848938+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-13 05:48:07 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2016-07-13T05:48:07.793789+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named 'app.Models.flight'
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

If I run `gunicorn app:app` locally, it will successfully launch the app with localhost.

If I deploy to heroku, it fails to launch the app.

I'd appreciate any input.
EDIT: 
**init**.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
from flask import Flask

sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
# from flask.ext.login import LoginManager

###############################################################################
# Configuration
###############################################################################
# Flask application setting
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config.update(dict(
    DEBUG = True,
    SECRET_KEY = '#####',
    USERNAME = '######',
    PASSWORD = '######'
))
app.config.from_envvar('APP_SETTING', silent=True)
app.config['basedir'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Manager authentication with LoginManager
# Handle Login with LoginManager
# manager = LoginManager()
# manager.init_app(app)
# manager.login_view = 'login'

# This import here has to be at the bottom of this file
# To avoid circular references
from app.Views import views
```

Comment: You are missing the `__init__.py` in your package folders.

Comment: it's there. unless you meant different "package folders" ?

Comment: In **every** package folder! That is every folder with a `.py` file.

Comment: with the same content/code in those __init__.py files?

Comment: If you don't have any special package initialization code it should be empty.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have code in your top level `__init__.py` that overloads the package / module names?

Comment: `app` is overloaded. In general, do not put your main code in `__init__.py`. It is ment for package initialization only. Use a separate file. And make sure variable, module and package names do not clash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117168/discussion-between-csessh-and-klaus-d).